# How to solve the problem that failed to npm run Vue2 project

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

**Question**

I try to npm run the Vue2 demo in 2019. But it failed to achieve the result.
Have tried to change to node.js 12, but it didn't work as well.

**Error**

```
#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# Check failed: U_SUCCESS(status).
#
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 000000880F6FD440npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 3221225477
npm ERR! readmore@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 3221225477
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the readmore@0.1.0 serve script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Anonymous\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-11-15T01_11_48_976Z-debug.log
/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm: line 34:   752 Segmentation fault      "$NODE_EXE" "$NPM_CLI_JS" "$@"
```

*Package.json*

```
{
  "name": "readmore",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.10.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.10.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `npm install` or `rm -rf node_modules` and then `npm install` again?

Comment: Yes, it's still the same.

Comment: I suggest you re-install the Node.js completely because `line 34:   752 Segmentation fault      "$NODE_EXE" "$NPM_CLI_JS" "$@"` seems like something is broken

Comment: Check and append the log file the error is mentioning. Google `nodejs/npm: line 34: 752 Segmentation fault` - there is a lot of result you can check and try